# Runtime Error '438' "Object doesn't support this propert or method"

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

Could you please help me resolve the issue on my Excel VBA file? Getting the error `Runtime Error '438' "Object doesn't support this propert or method"`

The error occurs on the following line: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Label2.Caption = DateValue(Now)`

```
Sub auto_open()
'    Call Worksheets(1).Label1
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lists() As String


    Worksheets("Sheet1").Label2.Caption = DateValue(Now)

    Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "XFB2:XFB8"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "XFC2:XFC4"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox3.ListFillRange = "XFD2:XFD14"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Label2` exists in `Sheet1`?

Comment: What is the label's actual name?

Comment: @ Fred, I am not sure if Label2 exists In the sheet...how can I check this?

Comment: Marek, I am not sure how to check the Labels name?Thank you for your responses. I've edited the VBA as per Marek advise but now when edited I am receiving this error: Run-time error '1004': Labels method of Worksheet class failed

Any idea why?

Please note that I have a Date cell in the worksheet that since the error of 438 is not automatically refreshing with Today's Date as it was previously..

Thank you in advance for looking at it again.

Comment: Hi Mark when I click on the cell that's causing an error(I think) I went to Properties and there is 2 fields showing a Name: (Name)-Folha2; and Name: Sheet1 ....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference to the label like that as the label is only one item from Labels collection.

You reference it either by id like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Labels(1)
```

or by name like this

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Labels("Label 2")
```